# Sharepoint / Active Directory / DNS

Tags: dns, active-directory, sharepoint

As a newbie to SP / AD, could someone give me a bit of advice..

I need to set up a Sharepoint site, primarily for collaboration with people working in other countries. Our network doesn't have a domain, all the PCs are just in a workgroup. I know that Sharepoint needs AD for user control but does AD definitely need a DNS server?

We would like Sharepoint to be accessible on sharepoint.company.com (via externally-hosted DNS) but does AD have to have a DNS server in order to function correctly? I can set up a company.local domain or a sub-domain of company.com on our internal DNS server and allow the Sharepoint/AD server to update it. Then, I assume I can set up host-headers or whatever so that the sites are accessible on the main URL..?

I suppose the main question is does AD definitely need DNS and, if so, can I point it at it's own little domain that nobody else will see?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another authentication method for SharePoint.  Have you looked at that option?

And AD needs DNS.

[MS SharePoint Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx)

Comment: AD does not need to run the DNS server, unfortunately it is a bit long winded and I am not having any luck finding the links, but you can use an external DNS server with AD.

Comment: I'm not opposed to configuring a DNS server so that we can use AD authentication - I'm just wondering if anything other than the Sharepoint server itself needs to see it. Will an internal companyname.local domain do or does it need to be a proper, externally-resolvable domain?